# Retrieving timestamp value from MySQL database returns current date

Tags: php, mysql, date, timestamp, return

When retrieving "timestamp" value from MySQL table, my php file always returns the current date, not the timestamp date in which the row was added to MySQL table.

I know for sure that timestamp works right when adding new rows in MySQL, I´ve checked phpMyAdmin and values are right. But when I ask to retrieve them using php, all the entries are returned as current date, showing the date in which I´m asking MySQL to return the data, not the original timestamp value.

My timestamp attributes in MySQL are the following ones:

name: fecha / type: TIMESTAMP / null: FALSE / default value: CURRENT_TIMESTAMP

I´m using the following code to retrieve the timestamp values (I had to create a few variables to translate the English timestamp to Spanish):

```
    $query = mysql_query ("SELECT * FROM news;");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array ($query)){
        
            $row_date = strtotime ($row["fecha"]);
            date ("F j, Y", $row_date);
            $dias = array("Domingo","Lunes","Martes","Miercoles","Jueves","Viernes","Sábado");
            $meses = array("Enero","Febrero","Marzo","Abril","Mayo","Junio","Julio","Agosto","Septiembre","Octubre","Noviembre","Diciembre");
                    
    echo $dias[date('w')]." ".date('d')." de ".$meses[date('n')-1]. " del ".date('Y') ;
    }
```

Comment: Try this $date = date("F j, y",$row_date); echo $date;

Comment: It might be returning within correct form but you might be echoing it in wrong way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to pass $row_date to every date() call.

```
echo date('Y', $row_date) ;
```

Comment: Wow, that was sharp. You´re right, I did only pass date() call to F j Y. I´ve got to try adding w d n into the "date" function and see if that works.